# Est-ce que "si" peut exprimer une question?

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce que le terme "si" peut marquer une question plutôt qu'une possibilité?
Exemple: Il faut que je sache si l'application est sûre.
En vous remerciant.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que dans l'exemple donné, c'est encore une possibilité:

> Il faut que je sache si l'application est sûre **(ou non)**.

On pourrait peut-être dire que la notion de possibilité et celle de question sont liées a une incertitude, c'est peut-être la le fil conducteur commun.

Comment: Je pense comprendre ce que vous dîtes.
Le mot "si" indique que la proposition qui suit est incertaine ou est une possibilité. Donc on peut dire "l'application est sûre" est une possibilité?

Answer (score 0):

Oui, comme par exemple :

> Je voudrais vous demander si vous acceptez les réservations. (= Acceptez-vous les réservations ?)